# coldfusion unable to load library null error for c++ custom tag, c++ build not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have been upgrading from coldfusion mx 7 in 32 bit windows server 2003 to coldfusion 10 in 64 bit windows server 2008.

When I put in my codefusion code in wwwwroot folder and go to localhost to test my website, I get "unable to load library null". I researched this problem and from this http://john-sieber.com/post/unable-to-load-library-null-error-with-coldfusion-custom-tag and other sites, it seem 32 bit c++ dll file for my cf custom tag does not work in my new 64 bit machine.

So to solve this problem, I got visual studio 2008 and decided to rebuild the dll in 64 bit. The c++ source code was originally created in vc++ 6 and when I tried to open the project solution file (.sln), it gave me xxx.vcproj could not be loaded. The project is either missing from disk or acess was denied. But I was able to open the file using new Project from existing code. After that I went to the configuration manager and changed platform to x64 and build the dll file successfully.

Using the new 64 bit dll file, i still get "unable to load library null" error. Further, the original 32 bit dll file was 1.5 mb while the new dll I build is only 148 kb. Any suggestion on what I did wrong or what should I do?

Mgetz suggested I open the project file instead of solution. When I tried to open .dsp project file, I get "cannot load the project due to a corrupt project file" error. In the source folder, i dont have a .vcproj file, i have .sln, .dsw and .dsp files plus .h, .cpp, .def and .rc files.

Comment: try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6dsak0e(v=vs.80).aspx don't know if it will work but it's worth a try, NOTE: you may need to have VS 2005 installed for this to work

Comment: Might I ask what the custom tag is doing for you? Since you are upgrading from ColdFusion 7 to ColdFusion 10 there may be better options for you. Perhaps even built-in to the newer version of ColdFusion itself.

Comment: There are four cfxs: remoteshell, getenvvar. setconfigspec and fmakefree, if i cant get the custom tag to work, i will probably use use build in tag to do the same thing.